# Vue - Passing same data from one component to many component

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have the following code.

**main.js**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    // this does not pass the data to the component
    <basics :resume="resume"></basics>
    <education :resume="resume"></education>
    // this gets the value from the json file
    {{resumeData.name}}
    {{resumeData.education}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import Basics from './components/Basics.vue'
import Education from './components/Education.vue'
import Resume from '../resume.json'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data() {
    return {
      resumeData: Resume
    }
  },
  components: {
    Basics,
    Education
  }
}
</script>
```

**/components/Basics.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>Basics</p>
        // this does not get the value from the json file
        {{resumeData.name}}
    </div>
</template>
```

**/components/Education.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>Education</p>
        {{resumeData.education}}
    </div>
</template>
```

How do I pass the data from one component to another such that all the different vue components is reading data from the same json file without inserting the code `import Resume from '../resume.json` in each component?

I hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 1):

A more common / standard way is just use props. Or you have to import the json in all your components.

If you have *many* components and really don't want to pass the same prop several times, there is tricky solution: inject the data to the Vue.prototype globally:

```
Vue.prototype.$resume = {
  name: 'foo',
  education: 'bar',
  ...
}
```

with this, all your components can access it via `this.$resume`. But use it wisely.

If you have other similar cases, you probably should go for [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/).

Answer (score 0):

In vue.js course you can solve this in 3 different ways.

1. Use props to pass data in Basics and Education
2. Vuex
3. Event box